# ProgressView inside SwiftUI List disappearing after list is updated

Tags: list, swiftui, onappear, swift5.7, ios16.2

The circular (default) SwiftUI `ProgressView` disappears within a `List` whenever the list gets expanded with new content because of a `.onAppear` modifier on the ProgressView.

The ProgressView becomes invisible, although its allocated cell (and its label, if assigned) within the list remain visible.

I want to keep the ProgressView at the bottom of the list so that the list gets automatically updated with new content being downloaded from the server when the user reaches the end of the list.

Possible duplicate of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71406903/swiftui-progressview-not-showing-when-inside-list) but the accepted answer does not tackle the reason why the view disappears.

Reprex:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var items: [String] = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"]
        
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
                    .frame(height: 100)
            }
            
            ProgressView {
                Text("Loading")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, alignment: .center)
            .onAppear(perform: endOfListReached)
        }
    }
    
    func endOfListReached() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            items.append("Item \(items.count + 1)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have to have a `List` or would a `ScrollView` be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather keep the List for its convenient layout, but it appears that the List is causing the issue here and that changing it to a ScrollView and LazyVStack and styling it with Dividers works as expected.

Comment: Just clarify that the ProgressView has to be inside the LazyVStack. Otherwise the .onAppear event only happens once.

Comment: @zephyr correct!

Comment: Thanks!
I've also learned about ScrollView + LazyVStack. It's the same than using a List view?

Comment: @FedeCugliandolo List uses UITableView's mechanism of reusing views. LazyVStack only loads views on demand of rendering them on screen but still keeping all of the views in memory. Therefore List is much more efficient in context of performance

Answer (score 0):

I believe had this same issue with the ProgressView disappearing, and what I ended up doing to solve it was to make a `@State var showProgressView: Bool` and setting it to true on the `onAppear` of the view, and false on the `onDisappear`. Put the ProgressView within an if statement that checks the boolean and that should make the ProgressView persist even when the content it is within unloads then reloads.